# Subqueries and Combining Queries together

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem I've been working on. I've broken it down to a couple of steps below. I have trouble combining all the queries together to solve the following:

> Find members who have spent over $1000 in departments that have
>   brought in more than $10000 total ordered by the members' id.

Schema:

```
departments(id, name)
products (id, name, price)
members(id, name, number, email, city, street_name, street_address)
sales(id, department_id, product_id, member_id, transaction_date
```

Step 1) 
I found the departments that have brought in more than 10,000$

```
select s.department_id
from sales s join products p on 
  s.product_id = p.id 
group by s.department_id
having sum(price) > '10000'
```

Step 2) I found the members and the departments that they shop in

```
select *
from members m
     join sales s
     on m.id = s.member_id 
     join departments d 
     on d.id = s.department_id
```

Step 3) I combined 1 and 2 to find members taht shop in departments that have brought in more than 10,000

```
select *
from members m
     join sales s
     on m.id = s.member_id 
     join departments d 
     on d.id = s.department_id
where s.department_id in 
    (select s.department_id
    from sales s join products p on 
    s.product_id = p.id 
    group by s.department_id
    having sum(price) > '10000')
```

Step 4) I found members and their id, email, total_spending > 1,000$

```
select m.id, m.name, m.email, sum(price) as total_spending
from members m join sales s on 
  m.id = s.member_id 
  join products p on 
  p.id = s.product_id 
group by m.id 
having sum(price) > '1000'
```

Step 5) 
All of the steps work individually but when I put them together in my attempt:

```
select m.id, m.name, m.email, sum(price) as total_spending
from members m join sales s on 
  m.id = s.member_id 
  join products p on 
  p.id = s.product_id 
where m.id in (select distinct m.id
from members m
     join sales s
     on m.id = s.member_id 
     join departments d 
     on d.id = s.department_id
where s.department_id in 
    (select s.department_id
    from sales s join products p on 
    s.product_id = p.id 
    group by s.department_id
    having sum(price) > '10000'))
group by m.id
having sum(price) > '1000'
```

The output is wrong. (This is on CodeWars) If someone could point me in the right direction that would be really great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to group by `member_id` and `department_id`:

```
select s.member_id,s.department_id,sum(p.price) as total_spending
from members m
join sales s on m.id = s.member_id
join products p on p.id = s.product_id
where s.department_id in (
        select s.department_id
        from sales s
        join products p on s.product_id = p.id
        group by s.department_id
        having sum(p.price) > 10000 -- the departments which brought in more than $10000 total
    )
group by s.member_id,s.department_id
having sum(p.price) > 1000 -- who have spent over $1000 in one department
```

And if you need you will able to calc how much spent each of members:

```
select member_id,sum(total_spending) total
from
  (
    -- the first query is here
  ) q
group by member_id
```

Comment: Hi Sergei, thank you for your help! Unfortunately, I'm not getting any results now!

Comment: Could you give some test data where conditions are true and false? For examples: 1) a member has more than 1000$ by one department; 2) a member has more 1000$ but by several departments (400$ in the first and 700$ in the second); 3) no members who has more than 1000$ but have departments which bought more than 10,000$; 4) etc. If you write down test data into your question I think you will get right answers sooner.